# Python Can't Find Module After Installing with Pip and Conda

Tags: python

I am on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I've defined an environment and I am trying to add the `palettable` package to it. This is what I tried:

1. `conda install palettable`, went fine no errors, tried to do `import palettable` in my script and I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'palettable'`
2. Next I did `conda remove palettable`
3. Then I installed again, this time using pip by doing `pip install palettable`
4. I get the same error

Did I miss a step? Or do something wrong?
I've added many other packages to this same environment using `conda` and not had any problems or encountered this error before.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix this problem by restarting the kernel or IDE in which you are writing the code after installing the module..

Comment: I tried that. I closed my IDE and I closed my WSL session. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Could it be because I didn't use `sudo`? I just tried a different package, `pip install brewer2mpl` and I am getting the same error.

Comment: It's something with Jupyter NB. I just created a new NB file and now it imports it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I am using VSCode and I didn't realize the python interpreter and the notebook kernel are set independently. The interpreter correctly reflected that I was using my project environment. But the notebook kernel (top right corner of NB window) was not set to the same thing. Once I set it correctly and restarted the IDE it now is correctly finding the packages.